# How do I change the "Default" password

Tags: 10.04

here's my problem. When I log in I'm beeing asked for a password connecting to the internet which is strange because I'm the only user and the admin. I have auto log in and it never asks for passwords, (except when i do administrative tasks.)
I have looked in the menu (System --> preferences, but i can't find any topic that say's passwords or similar. the only place where I have found a way to change my password is my user ((System --> preferences --> user and groups).
I did try to take screenshots but nothing happened, which also is strange.

I'm running ubuntu 10.04 LTS Desktop on my Asus 1201n (12").

Comment: Are you connecting via wireless or wired connection. I had this same problem with a wireless connection when I was set up for auto login. I think the problem is that the WPA password for the wireless connection is stored on your ubuntu account's key ring, and since you did not authenticate when logging in, you need to authenticate when trying to bring up the network connection. You might try changing the configuration of your connection in Network Manager to be available for all users and this may allow the connection without you needing to be authenticated to use it.

Comment: thanks this works! I canged all the passwd with (sudo passwd) after I did what you said.

Comment: I've voted up Dennis's comment - suggest you do the same.  Should have been an "answer" though and would therefore have claimed the "accepted" reputation too.

Comment: how do i up vote the comment?

Comment: I didn't want to post my suggestion as an answer since it was just speculation and could not test it myself. I'm glad it helped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's also possible that since your using auto-login, you might be hitting another problem - sometimes network manager doesn't seem to save the WEP/WPA key properly.  You can usually get round this by opening the connection and changing it "available to all users".

So, right click on network manager, choose "Edit Connections".  Find your connection, and choose "Properties", then tick the "Available to all users" box at the bottom.

[image]

Comment: This answer is the same as the comment is on my first post. But it works! woho!

Comment: True.  Didn't think it was the same issue though, so I put two answers to cover both possibilities.  Answers shouldn't be made in comments (although sometimes it just happends!) - only "answers" can be "accepted".

Comment: well we have to just up vote the comment then.. :)

Comment: There is only one user so LOL

Comment: That's irrelevant, really - the main thing is that ticking that box bypasses the use of gnome-keyring for saving your password.  Instead, it's dumped in a root-only-readable file somewhere in /etc.  It's less secure, but seems more reliable.  Having said that, I haven't seen this "bug" since Lucid LTS 10.04.  Maverick 10.10 has been fine for me.  I haven't upgraded to Natty 11.04 yet, so can't comment.

Answer (score 10):

Sounds like your keychain is out of sync with your password.  Go to System/Preferences/Password and Encryption keys, then choose the "login" chain.

[image: Seahorse]

The only way that I *know* works is to set this to a blank password - you will be prompted on whether you are willing to trust this "unsafe storage" method, since your keyring will unlock automatically on login.

I *think* you can also match the password on the login keychain to match that of your login password.  But a) I haven't tested that and b) you have to remember to change your keychain password whenever you change your login password.

As the only person on my laptop, configured with encrypted home, I'm happy with unsafe storage, but your mileage may vary.

Comment: I don't have a menu trail that leads to a password and encription key! My menu start with personal file sharing and over that is a openjdk java.

Comment: It's possible that "Passwords and Encryptions keys" is still in the Applications/Accessories menu for you.  It was moved in 10.10, I think.  Could be wrong.  You can open a terminal and do `sudo apt-get install seahorse` to install it if you don't have it.

Comment: You may still have this in Applications/Accessories.  If you can't it there either, try using ALT-F2 and enter `seahorse`.  If that doesn't work, you don't have it installed.  Use `sudo apt-get install seahorse` to install it.

Comment: haha, it is under applications accessories! awesome!

Comment: It was changed to system/preferences in 10.10, I think, which makes sense now that I notice you're running 10.04.

Answer (score 4):

> Chrome asks for the password when your account is set for autologin.
> Doing this makes it so that the keyring doesn't load when you
> reset/reboot your system.
>
> Chrome is asking for the password to the keyring so it can access
> stored information in the keyring. You can view the keyring on your
> system by running the command seahorse from a terminal window. You can
> also just bypass the asking by closing the window and still get to
> your sites without a problem. Some of the security may not load
> properly.
>
> However, you can use the following command from a terminal window to
> bypass the keyring asking:
>
> ```
> google-chrome-stable --password-store=basic
> ```
>
> Hope this helps!

*Copied entirely from [@Terrance's answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/884903/158442)*

Comment: I use autologin with full disk encryption.

Answer (score 1):

In order to change the root password, open a terminal

```
sudo passwd
```

When asked, provide your user password in order to perform sudo tasks, then enter the "new UNIX password" twice.

Now the root user has a new password.

You will see something like this:

```
geppettvs@HANNAH:~$ sudo passwd
[sudo] password for geppettvs: 
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password: 
passwd: password updated successfully
geppettvs@HANNAH:~$
```

Good luck!

Comment: If you're using encrypted home, this will break your install.  You should use the Me Menu to change your password.

Comment: It didn't broke with mine, but thanks for the warning.

Comment: And you're using encrypted home too?

Comment: Yes I do. :) :) :)

Comment: changing your password doesn't break encrypted home. using `passwd` is safe at all times. it is the backend to any GUI allowing that btw. however, this answer is unrelated to the OP.

Comment: @StéphaneHesse is right, somehow I don't remember answering this question with such, it seems other answers, like Alvar's answer, do refer to the same question we tried to help. Maybe was this question merged with another one? I don't have enough privileges to check. Thank you for pointing to this error, anyway it wasn't me.