# How to get rid of google chrome keyring

Tags: google-chrome, keyrings

I have recently switched from firefox to google chrome on Ubuntu 16.04.  The keyring application is really starting to annoy me.  It keeps prompting me for password for no apparent reason.  Also google chrome randomly seems to forget passwords for some sites.  I would like to completely disable the keyring feature and have it just remember my passwords without me needing to enter another password.  I do not care to much about security since this is my personal system that no one else has access to.  How can I make chrome remember my passwords without every prompting me with keyring.

Comment: This answer looks better http://askubuntu.com/a/191490/167115

Comment: Check this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/495957/how-to-disable-the-unlock-your-keyring-popup/1034053#1034053). You may instruct Chrome to do not use the keyring by using the option `--password-store=basic`. e.g, you may run chrome by `$ google-chrome --password-store=basic`

Comment: Ubuntu users will prefer [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/968149/227779) instead, because it uses relevant file paths

Answer (score 10):

In my Ubuntu MATE, go to **Applications > Accessories > Passwords and Keys**

You can also load it from shell: `seahorse`.

Then delete the "default" keyring.

Then reopen Chrome/ium again. It should prompt for password. Enter your password and check "remember". It worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

For Ubuntu 16.04 Open "Password and Keys"

In the view and make sure "By Keyring" option is checked.

Then in the left side, right click on keyring (or default keyring whatever it is) and click on unlock.

It will ask for the password, for me this was the same I set in the first time I installed Ubuntu.

Even if you changed login password after installation, enter the password used for the first time... it should work. If it does, right click on keyring again and delete it (it will also delete any passwords it might have saved).

Comment: Where is that setting located?

Comment: I used the last sentence of this answer.  I deleted the Default Keyring and rebooted. Upon opening Google Chrome again, it asks to add a password to protect etc. I chose not to, then another popup warning about not being secure pops up I closed (ignored) that window.  Now the problem is fixed.

Comment: BTW, Google Chrome still keeps the passwords but you will have to login to your websites again, which usually is auto filled by Google like it was before this issue arrived.