# autofill passwords takes time to fill the field

Tags: google-chrome, 17.04

under Chrome, if I want to log into any page, I have to wait 15 seconds until Chrome autofills the credential fields. This happens on all sites which have saved passwords, even new passwords saved using Google Chrome!

What's wrong with Chrome? I have no such problem with Firefox on the same computer with even more saves passwords as I've been using firefox for a longer time before the days of Chrome.

I went to chrome://sync-internals/ and no issues there

Comment: Have a look at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=389139

Comment: CodeAlfa's answer worked like a charm  Maybe you should consider to make it the accepted answer.

Comment: It was risky that's why I couldn't consider it as an answer. Thanks to Allah the bug is fixed now by Chrome team

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome has fixed the bug and now available as per this bug report https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=571003

Answer (score 3):

I have been having this issue for a while and I found an answer to a similar questions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31786/chrome-asks-for-password-to-unlock-keyring-on-startup#answer-968149) that seems to resolve this. In short, copy `google-chrome.desktop` file to your home folder and edit it to use the 'Basic' password storage setting:

```
cp /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/
```

Then look for the line that looks like this:

```
Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %U
```

And change it to:

```
Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --password-store=basic %U
```

I also had a number of files in the `~/.local/share/applications/` folder that looked like `Chrome-jdj94r5hsfjnfasdfsdfafp-Default.desktop` that seemed to have been placed there over time based on the timestamps but I deleted them all.

Saved passwords now show up immediately when the page is loaded.

Comment: but won't this store passwords in clear text which could be a huge security threat?

Comment: Thanks. Looked everywhere for a way to fix this. Not too worried about passwords potentially being stored in plain text as using full drive encryption reduces that risk to some degree.