# Chrome Shows all passwords without asking for login password

Tags: login, google-chrome, password, security, keyrings

I use Ubuntu 18.4 with the latest Chrome. I am facing this issue that Chrome shows all my password (on clicking the eye button) without asking for any login password. How can I enable it?

---

While Chrome might be similar to Chromiun certain aspects can be differnt. So how is this a duplicate?

Comment: No. Only in Ubuntu. Windows 10 asks for password.

Comment: For some reason it is password protected in windows, not linux. I suppose it is because this makes windows users feel safe and partially because in a Unix environment, users have separate accounts. You can make your home more private or you can encrypt home if you wish.

Comment: @Panther Please see this link (https://askubuntu.com/questions/31786/chrome-asks-for-password-to-unlock-keyring-on-startup), do you know how could we do the other way round?