# Can you make keyring unlock automatically even during autologin?

Tags: xubuntu, keyrings, auto-login

I use full disk encryption, so I think I do not need manual keyring unlocking. I want to get rid of chromium-browser requesting me to unlock keyring when I star it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/31786/chrome-asks-for-password-to-unlock-keyring-on-startup

Comment: @ThomasWard actually, I made this separate question because I think it might be better to set keyring to unlock automatically rather than make chromium-browser use basic unencrypted password store. But I may be wrong. And the answer could be told in another thread, as well, but I would not know it.

Comment: This is how it works on Fedora by default, so it *should* be possible. @jarno, did you end up ever finding a solution to this? I'm looking for one now.

Comment: @daboross no I did not