# How do I completely remove Keyrings from system?

Tags: password, uninstall, keyrings

None of the answers seem to do the trick nd youtube videos talk about putting in a default password; but that is like storing your passwords in a safe and leaving the safe unlocked.

All my passwords are unique, and I use a formula that I have memorized to apply the correct password to any site.  I manage my own passwords and refuse to use a password manager of any type.

What I want to do is DELETE keyring so it does not function in any capacity.  Firefox doesn't prompt me to enter a keyring so neither should Chrome.

Here is what I have found and tried.

From a command prompt I typed "seahorse" and it ran the password keyring and let me delete the pre-defined profiles in it.

Then I tried chrome several times and it was gone, but as soon as I rebooted, and loaded Chrome again, it came back.  So I repeated the above step and after that I did the follwing at a command prompt.

```
sudo apt purge seahorse
```

It successfully removed it, but when I reboot and load chrome, once again it wants a keyring.

I then typed the following.

```
sudo rm ~/.local/share/keyrings -fr
```

keyrings are gone, but as soon as I reboot and load chrome, it's back again. At a command prompt I typed

```
keyring --disable
```

rebooted, and again chrome still prompts me for keyring. Next I looked in the profile.d and I didin't see anything in there running it.

There has to be a way to destroy the keyring program completely so it never even runs.  Anybody?

Comment: Hello. What you want to do is in my opinion a bad idea. You have not provided any Ubuntu version info in this question.

Comment: I don't like the built-in keyring either especially since I already use a separate password manager. To not use a password manager at all is adding unnecessary effort on your part for no gain however.

Comment: Version is 22.04 "Jammy".  I would rather have the extra effort and be under my COMPLETE control.  I don't trust any "password manager".  To me that is the same as handing the keys to your home off to some company under the promise they won't enter your home.  It's dangerous to do that and I have a formula to help me remember my passwords.

Answer (score 4):

As you purged `seahorse`, you effectively managed to remove Keyrings from system. So there, you provided the answer to your own question and you are fine.

However, the problem you continue to see is Chrome still asking for a keyring, even if you removed keyrings. It is a matter of instructing Chrome to [use the "basic" password store](https://askubuntu.com/a/968149/558158).