# How to close the mouth of chromium for asking gnome-keyring password?

Tags: chromium

I use Ubuntu 13.10.

I don't like to put my password at each time.

How to attain the logging without password entry ?

Comment: Look at [the answer "from 12.10 onwards"](http://askubuntu.com/a/224777/117103)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25974/how-do-i-change-the-default-password/25999#25999) you can set the keyring password to blank.

> Go to System/Preferences/Password and Encryption keys, right click the appropriate folder and click Change Password. Put in your old password and leave the new one blank.

[Answer taken from here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31786/chrome-asks-for-password-to-unlock-keyring-on-startup)

Comment: I mistook the buttons, sorry. Now it has my answer.