# Chromium saved passwords are not loaded until save a password

Tags: chromium, 16.04, keyrings

I don't have a password for keyring. When I start my laptop, chromium saved passwords are not loaded until I save a password by chromium, then the passwords are accessible until next reboot.

Why chromium saved passwords are not accessible until I use keyring at least once, and how to fix it?

Comment: Does your computer auto-login?

Comment: @Tim yes, Ubuntu comes with auto-login.

Comment: Disabling that would fix it

Comment: @Tim I want to use auto-login. How can I fix the problem without sacrificing something else?

Answer (score 0):

Set the keyring password to blank.  Put your password in it, and then leave the new password without an entry.

[How do I change the "Default" password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25974/how-do-i-change-the-default-password/25999#25999)