# Ubuntu Keyring on Library Public Computers

Tags: boot, grub2, password, security

For context, I'm putting together a couple of computers for public use at my library. I've set up Lethe to use a frozen OS install to reset everything on boot, and I'm using Clonezilla to image and reinstall the OS and our custom set-up when anything goes wrong. The computers boot directly into the public (and non-passworded) user account.

I'm a bit confused about the Keyring message ('Choose password for new Keyring') that pops up every time I open Chromium. It's annoying and confusing for customers. Most of the solutions I've seen for getting rid of it just come down to setting a password.

If I did this, would I be inadvertently storing customer passwords? And, even if so, would this be a realistic concern given that GRUB and Lethe are resetting that instance of the OS every boot?

-UPDATE
I may have worded my question incorrectly. I'm more wondering what the Keyring is actually doing here, and whether I should set a password for the Keyring, leave it without a default password, or disable Keyring entirely. My concern is around keeping customers secure and not inadvertently retaining their information, because it sounds like Keyring does save user's information to the hard disk.

Comment: Possible:  https://askubuntu.com/a/884903/231142

Answer (score 1):

Really, for a public terminal that's always logged in and running in this manner, you should probably write some custom config to the system for Chromium, to force the password management, autofill, and other sensitive options to off, so that personal details and passwords do not get saved. You'd also need to hide/disable the "sign into Google" feature of Chromium to enable sync.

Yes, being able to store any of this information on a public computer for any length of time, is a realistic concern. If one person were to enter their credit card details, or log into some site, and the data got saved, the next person sitting down could then access that information.