# Make Firefox ask for master password when PC unlocked or VNC session

Tags: firefox, password, remote-desktop, vnc

I use Ubuntu 16.04 with Firefox 53 in my office. I lock my computer every night but I don't close Firefox.

Other people might have access to my machine, with the same user, using VNC o directly unlocking the machine with the Ubuntu password.

How can I force Firefox to ask for the master password if the computer was unlocked or accessed on a remote session?

Comment: I think you have a design problem in your office: if you want to have private data in your FF you should get rid of "Other people might have access to my machine, with the same user". Otherwise it will always be insecure.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a bit of a disapointing answer but the silver lining is that other responders reading this might be given an idea for your perfect solution: Google Chrome under Ubuntu does this by default.

Funily enough [it's something most people don't want](https://www.google.fr/search?q=ubuntu+chrome+unlock+keyring&oq=ubuntu+chrome+unlock+keyring&aqs=chrome..69i57.9796j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

But I suspect you can use the keyring features:
[How do I change the "Default" password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25974/how-do-i-change-the-default-password/25999#25999)
to trigger and lock firefox when waking from suspend or being unlocked in general.

If not then I'm sorry for the wild goose chase. I'll edit this answer as more info rolls in.

In the meantime using Chrome could be a workaround.